# calculate angle in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
       City x-Coord  City y-Coord                     coord
12860    59333.3333    18050.0000       (59333.3333+18050j)   
12941    59350.0000    18050.0000            (59350+18050j)   
13035    59366.6667    18050.0000       (59366.6667+18050j)   
12940    59350.0000    18033.3333       (59350+18033.3333j)   
13034    59366.6667    18016.6667  (59366.6667+18016.6667j)   
13033    59366.6667    18000.0000       (59366.6667+18000j)   
13132    59383.3333    18000.0000       (59383.3333+18000j)   
13133    59383.3333    18016.6667  (59383.3333+18016.6667j)   
13134    59383.3333    18033.3333  (59383.3333+18033.3333j)   
13230    59400.0000    18033.3333       (59400+18033.3333j)
```

Now, to calculate the angle between city 1(x), 2(y) and 3(z):

```
arccos(np.dot((x-y),(z-y))/(abs(x-y)*abs(z-y))
```

So, how I have calculated is:

```
df['combined'] = list(zip(df['City x-Coord'], df['City y-Coord']))
df['combined'] = df['combined'].apply(np.array)
a = df['combined'] - df['combined'].shift(1)
b = df['combined'] - df['combined'].shift(-1)
df['angle'] = [np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(x, y) / (np.linalg.norm(x) * np.linalg.norm(y)))).round().astype(int) for
               x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

But, I am not getting angles right.

```
df.head()
```

Out[5]:

```
       City x-Coord  City y-Coord                     coord  \
12860    59333.3333    18050.0000       (59333.3333+18050j)   
12941    59350.0000    18050.0000            (59350+18050j)   
13035    59366.6667    18050.0000       (59366.6667+18050j)   
12940    59350.0000    18033.3333       (59350+18033.3333j)   
13034    59366.6667    18016.6667  (59366.6667+18016.6667j)   
                       combined       angle  
12860     [59333.3333, 18050.0] -2147483648  
12941        [59350.0, 18050.0]         180  
13035     [59366.6667, 18050.0]          45  
12940     [59350.0, 18033.3333]          90  
13034  [59366.6667, 18016.6667]         135
```

Also, last value is also wrong, because of NaN value.

```
df.tail()
```

Out[6]:

```
       City x-Coord  City y-Coord                     coord  \
12677    59300.0000    18100.0000            (59300+18100j)   
12761    59316.6667    18083.3333  (59316.6667+18083.3333j)   
12863    59333.3333    18100.0000       (59333.3333+18100j)   
12862    59333.3333    18083.3333  (59333.3333+18083.3333j)   
12861    59333.3333    18066.6667  (59333.3333+18066.6667j)   
                       combined       angle  
12677        [59300.0, 18100.0]         135  
12761  [59316.6667, 18083.3333]          90  
12863     [59333.3333, 18100.0]          45  
12862  [59333.3333, 18083.3333]         180  
12861  [59333.3333, 18066.6667] -2147483648
```

1st and last entry I can understand, as Nan value. Can i change the dict comprehension to fix that? Also, is my calculation correct? Not sure. Can somebody please give a second opinion.

Thanks,
Arnab

Comment: What is the purpose of your `coord` column then? And what is your angle measurement relative to?

Comment: coord column is transforming it to complex to make calculations easier.....angle: it is the angle in degrees between pt1-->pt2 vector and pt2--->pt3 vector(row1,2 and 3)

Comment: But you never use that column....

Comment: true, i used another method, but that also should work fine, please let me know if you feel otherwise

Comment: If you don't use that column, then I wouldn't include it in your post. Also, I only see an 'x-coord' column and 'y-coord' column, nothing for z...